# How to work with camera image

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to create a sensor plugin for camera sensor. Following the source code for [gazebo_ros_camera](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/jade-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera.cpp) plugin, I assume, that a CameraPlugin has an OnNewFrame() callback function that is called whenever the camera captures a frame. The callback function than gets the image as **const unsigned char *_image**. But I do not understand how to get the actual image out of this data type. I want to add some information into each frame, such as simulation time, and then save the frame into a folder. How can this be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24867/how-to-work-with-camera-image/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2020-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found one way to get the image into cv::Mat format.

```
#include <cv.h>

void AddSimTimeToFrame::OnNewFrame(const unsigned char *_image,
                                    unsigned int _width, 
                                    unsigned int _height, 
                                    unsigned int _depth,
                                    const std::string &_format)
{
    // must be casted to void * to trigger the correct cv::Mat constructor
    void* data = (void*)_image;
    cv::Mat img(_height, _width, CV_8UC3, data);
    // the red and blue channels are switched 
    cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2RGB);
    
    // image processing
}
```

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0